# GPS State with Chinese phone (VeryKool S352)

Tags: android, gps

In my app, I'm checking the geolocalization state with this test
--> I need the user to have Wifi and GPS Enabled-

```
public boolean enableGPSifDown() {
    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
        return true;
```

The thing is in the cel (Android 4.2.2), all the GPS checkbox are cheked and wifi is on, nevertheless, this method always return false.

I've been using this method for all kind of cells ( Samsung, motorola, alcatel, sony, etc...) and never had problem with that, but with this "verykool" phone, it gives me false???

I have the permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Any idea other than change the phone????

Comment: Log each isProviderEnabled separately to see which is false. Also does the device have Google Play/Services and/or have a SIM in it?

Comment: yes, it pass the test :   if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this) == ConnectionResult.SERVICE_VERSION_UPDATE_REQUIRED). I will do the seperate test!

Comment: The failing test is : locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)

Comment: Don't have that phone make so you might want to put the exact model in your question. My thought is that it might need a SIM for AGPS to work.